# Nested functions in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I wish to use nested function in C++ in order to avoid global variables. I found a method for doing that by using classes (http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/058.htm). I tried to implement that solution but I failed. Here is my code :

```
class Myclass 
{
    double (*retval)(double, double);
double A;
double x0, y0, z0, z, a, b,k;
int mu, nu, s, t;

double g(double x, double y)
{
    return (x0+y0+z0+a+b+k+s+t+mu+nu)*A*x*y;
}
public :
Myclass(complex<double> A, double x0, double y0, double z0, double k, double a, double b,  int mu, int nu, int s, int t) : z(0.)
{
    this->A=A;
    this->x0=x0;
    this->y0=y0;
    this->z0=z0;
    this->k=k;
    this->a=a;
    this->b=b;
    this->mu=mu;
    this->nu=nu;
    this->s=s;
    this->t=t;
    retval=g;
}
operator double (double, double)
{
    return retval;
}
};

int main ()
{
    /*
    ....
   */
    return 0;
}
```

The goal is to return a function with the prototype double (double, double) which will be used for by other instructions.

I got this errors messages :

```
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp

main.cpp:114:36: error: ‘Myclass::operator double(double, double)’ must take ‘void’ operator double (double, double)
                                    ^
main.cpp: In constructor ‘Myclass::My_class(std::complex<double>, double, double, double, double, double, double, int, int, int, int)’:

main.cpp:112:15: error: cannot convert ‘Myclass::g’ from type ‘double (champ_speculaire_class::)(double, double)’ to type ‘double (*)(double, double)’ retval=g;
                 ^
```

Comment: What you mean is called _recursion_, the term _"nested function"_ is pretty irritating.

Comment: The compiler still declare the istruction
    this->retval=g; 
as an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The goal is to return a function with the prototype double (double, double)

```
operator double (double, double)
```

declares a [**conversion operator**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), *not* a function returning a function.

To return a function, and since you tagged your question with [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), I'd recommend using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
std::function<double(double, double)> get() const
{
    return retval;
}
```

The syntax of returning a function pointer to a `double(double, double)` function would look like this:

```
double (*get())(double, double) const
{
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: The OP simply want's recursion, rather returning a function (pointer) it seems.

Comment: The compiler still declare the instruction this->retval=g; as an error. How is it possible to avoid this error please ?

Comment: `g` is not a normal `double(double,double)` function, it's a _member_ function. If you want `retval` to be a [pointer to member function](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members), declare it as `double (Myclass::* retval)(double, double);`

Comment: My goal is to use the function g in an other function which have a double(double,double) parameter. May be set all the attributes to static in order to avoid the 'this' pointer ? I tried that and I succeeded to compile. I still have no idea if it is correct or not !!

Comment: @user5396848 A `double(*)(double, double)` cannot hold any state beyond "which function I am calling".  A pointer-to-a-class is state, as is the rest of your data.  What is the other function that expects a `double(*)(double,double)`, and why does it have that interface?

Comment: In fact, I have to integrate the function g. Thus I use a non-adaptive algorithm implemented in C++ for performing automatic cubature (http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=513006). 
The function is a member function of a class named DoubleIntegral. The prototype of this member function is :    void set_new_integral(double a, double b, BOUNDARY_FUNCTION g, BOUNDARY_FUNCTION h, INTEGRAND_FUNCTION f) 

where :

        BOUNDARY_FUNCTION = double (*)(double)
        INTEGRAND_FUNCTION = double (*)(double,double)